# C++ Vector size is returning zero

Tags: c++, vector, standard-library

The size() for vectors in C++ standard library returns zero
The size() is supposed to return the current number of elements.

Is something wrong with my code ? Or is it a bug in the function ?
It happens on MinGW compiler on my PC and also g++ compiler on Linux VW

The capacity() returns the expected result.

```
using namespace std;

    bool binarySearch(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
    {
    int low, high, mid;

        low = 0;
        high = nums.size();
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        printf("low %d high %d mid %d  \n", low, high, mid);

        return true;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int result;
        vector<int> v1;
        v1.reserve(30);
        v1[0] = 1;
        for (int index = 1; index < 30; index++)
        {
            v1[index] = v1[index-1] + (rand()%10);
        }

        bool flag = binarySearch(v1, 57);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I was confused for a moment as well since OP's code has for loop that setting each indexed element, but this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at it says the **operator [] never inserts new element**. So even you reserved and set the element, the elements did not get inserted (with no exception which is not very informative. You can use `std::vector::at` like `v1.at(0) = 1` and it will throw exception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add new elements using `v1.push_back(...)`. At the moment, you're simply reserving memory in the `vector` - which does not change the size, only its capacity.

Manipulating the `vector` with the index operator afterwards is bad style, you should only retrieve/edit elements which are already defined as "in the container". In contrast to other languages the index operator does not automatically add elements to your container. In your case you're simply manipulating some reserved memory. Note: the "checked" access method `at()` would throw an exception in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your explanation answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

`reserve` just pre-allocates memory, it does not change `size`. You could omit `reverse` and just use

```
vector<int> v1(30);
```

Alternatively, and perhaps better, you can utilize `push_back`:

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
for (int index = 1; index < 30; index++)
{
    v1.push_back(v1[v1.size()-1] + (rand()%10));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v1.reserve(30);
```

does not change the number of elements in the `vector`, it just makes sure the `vector` has enough space to save 30 elements without reallocation. Use

```
v1.resize(30);
```

to change to number of elements in the vector or use

```
std::vector<int> v1(30);
```

to initialize the `v1` to contain 30 `int`s initialized to 0.

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to read up on what the `std::vector` member functions do exactly.